# Enabling dashed option for biblatex-ieee style

Tags: biblatex, ieeetran, ieee-style

According to the `biblatex` manual, the dashed option is only available in `authortitle`, `authoryear` and `verbose` styles. Is it possible to enable this option for the `biblatex-ieee` style?

I want to disable putting dash when I have recurring author list. I did a hack by editing the `ieee.bbx` file but I am wondering if there is any better way to do it.

Comment: One of the advantages of `biblatex` is that you can alter the style in your LaTeX document. So you should be able to simply alter the `authors` bibliography macro in your preamble. Is that what you mean by 'hacking `ieee.bbx`?

Comment: @JosephWright, yes I modified the authors macro, but I don't like this method. there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It should be possible to disable dash substitution by adding

```
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{}
```

in the preamble (this is what the `dash` option for the standard styles mentioned does).

Comment: I can add this to `biblatex-ieee` if it is of more general interest, as an option modelled on the standard styles.

Comment: it would be great to have this possibility. Right now I have compiled with dashed=false and it says not recognized option.

Comment: @jlanza OK, I'll look into it