# Biblatex formats organisation wrong

Tags: biblatex, biber

I got a strange output when using the same Organisation as Author twice in my bibliography. The 2nd time the Author/Organisation Entry is used it is replaced with underscores.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@booklet{testlit:2012vz,
title = {{Testlit1}},
author = {{European Standard Company}},
howpublished = {Selbstverlag},
address = {Berlin},
month = oct,
year = {2012}
}
@booklet{testlit:2013tk,
title = {{Testlit2}},
author = {{European Standard Company}},
howpublished = {Selbstverlag},
address = {Berlin},
month = feb,
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[                
 bibstyle=ieee,
 citestyle=ieee,
 sorting=none,
 block=space,
 natbib=true,
 backend=biber
 ]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
 \urlstyle{same}

 \begin{document}
 hello \citep{testlit:2012vz}
 world \citep{testlit:2013tk}
 \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. That's not really wrong. It is a feature of some bibliography styles (such as, obviously, `ieee`), that repeated authors are replaced by a long dash.

Comment: See also [Get full name twice in Bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864)

Comment: More relevant [biblatex ieee style same authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131625/35864), [Enabling dashed option for biblatex-ieee style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70411/35864)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really wrong, it is a feature of the style you've chosen, that repeated authors are replaced by a long dash in the reference list.

You can however disable that feature by adding

```
dashed=false
```

to the `biblatex` options.

Comment: unfortunately older versions of ieee.bbx (texlive 2016) do not support the dashed option so I had to update to the most recent version. Anyway thanks!