# Author in one entry in bibliography not printed

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

In one certain entry of my bibliography the author is not printed, but just a '--'. In other entries there is no problem. What could be the reason.

This is the entry that causes trouble:

```
@article{josephson_discovery_1974,
    title = {The discovery of tunnelling supercurrents},
    volume = {46},
    doi = {10.1103/RevModPhys.46.251},
    abstract = {DOI:https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.46.251},
    journal = {Reviews of Modern Physics},
    author = {Josephson, B. D.},
    month = apr,
    year = {1974},
    note = {Publisher: American Physical Society},
    pages = {251--254},
}
```

For this entry the citation works as expected:

```
@article{josephson_possible_1962,
    title = {Possible new effects in superconductive tunnelling},
    volume = {1},
    issn = {0031-9163},
    doi = {10.1016/0031-9163(62)91369-0},
    journal = {Physics Letters},
    author = {Josephson, B. D.},
    month = jul,
    year = {1962},
    pages = {251--253},
}
```

For the citations in my file I use `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee]{biblatex}`. In the text I cite them by `\cite{josephson_possible_1962,josephson_discovery_1974}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The `iees` style is designed to replace the author field with `------` for entries with repeated author fields. It's not an error, it's a purposeful feature. If you can't stand this feature, though, just don't use the `ieee` style.

Comment: Ok, so that is the standard way. Why is that considered useful?

Comment: Do the two entries with the same author then always appear next to each other in the bibliography?

Comment: Sorry, but as I'm not the designer of the `ieee` style, I simply have no information as to *why* the actual designers chose this particular. Your second question, in contrast, is very easy to answer: It must be the case that the entire bibliography contains only one pair of entries with the same author -- here: `Josephson, B. D.`. Incidentally, since the `ieee` style sorts its entries first by surnames and then by year of publication, it's the `josephson_discovery_1974` entry and not the `josephson_possible_1962` entry that gets its author string replaced with `------`.

Comment: You ask, "Do the two entries with the same author then *always* appear next to each other in the bibliography?" [emphasis added] The answer is **yes** for any bibliography style that sorts the entries first by authors' surnames and then, if available, by a second criterion. This second criterion is often the entries' publication dates.

Comment: You also asked, "Why is that considered useful?" Unfortunately, why-type questions can only be answered truthfully by the person(s) who actually made the stylistic choices in question. (To repeat: I'm not that person.) By the way, what good might it do you to receive factual anwers to such why-type questions? If you've been told that you must use the `ieee` style, does it really matter to know *why* certain stylistic choices were made? Unless the answers help resolve some moral or ethical conflict (which I doubt is the case here!), answers to why-type questions simply don't matter either way.

Comment: @mico Thank you for your answers. The motivation for that why-type question is that one can indeed sometimes learn something from them  for other scenarios. Maybe a certain style makes a certain type of task easier that I did not immediately think of, but someone with a lot of experience came up with this solution.

Comment: I didn't claim that why-type questions are entirely pointless. I was pointing out that why-type questions regarding stylistic choices can only be answered meaningfully by the person(s) who actually made these choices -- and that I'm not that person, when it comes to the stylistic choices embedded in the `ieee` style.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70411/35864. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29381/35864. The answer to the why is most likely that it saves space (at least in non-numeric styles it may also help visually group entries, but in numeric styles this effect is not as pronounced).